# Problems with generics

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, generics, interface

I'm facing a problem with generics:

```
public interface IEntity {}

public class User : IEntity {}

public class Experiments {
    private IList<IEntity> list;
    private IList<Action<IEntity>> actions;

    public Experiments(){
        list = new List<IEntity>();
        actions = new List<Action<IEntity>>();
    }

    public void Add<T>(T entity) where T : IEntity {
        list.Add(entity); // -> NO PROBLEM HERE
    }

    public void AddAction<T>(Action<T> handle) where T : IEntity {
        actions.Add(handle); // -> HERE I GET AN ERROR
    }
```

Why I get *"cannot convert from 'System.Action<T>' to 'System.Action<IEntityCheck>..."* once I specified on the method's signature that T is IEntity?

Comment: `IEntity` != `IEntityCheck`

Comment: Did you copy the correct error message?  When I compile it I get:
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Action<IEntity>>.Add(System.Action<IEntity>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: If you know that `T` is an `IEntity`, why not use `IEntity` instead of generics?

Comment: @JohnKalberer See my comment under *JG in SD*'s answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
public void AddAction(Action<IEntity> handle) 
{
    actions.Add(handle);
}
```

And for your add function there is no need to add a type parameter, just use the interface.

```
public void Add(IEntity entity)
{
    list.Add(entity);
}
```

The issue with `public void AddAction<T>(T entity) where T : IEntity` is I could (if it worked) pass in a function like `Foo(ConcreteEntity entity)` that uses member on the concrete class, that are not defined on the interface, then I wouldn't be able to loop through the list of `Actions<IEntity>` and calling them all with some other implementation of `IEntity` and have them all succeed.

Comment: Of course this will work, but i guess the question is what is wrong with `public void Add<T>(T entity) where T : IEntity`

Comment: JG, don't reply to my comment and update your answer if you think it is the explanation.

Comment: +1 I think you got the point but it requires a better explanation. some examples maybe.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it to compile by declaring the generic type at the class level.

```
public interface IEntity { }

public class User : IEntity { }

public class Experiments<T> where T : IEntity
{
    private IList<T> list;
    private IList<Action<T>> actions;

    public Experiments()
    {
        list = new List<T>();
        actions = new List<Action<T>>();
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        list.Add(entity);
    }

    public void AddAction(Action<T> handle)
    {
        actions.Add(handle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for the answers, I figured out a way to solve the issue.

I just changed the actions *List<Action<T>> to List<Delegate>* and now all works fine...

```
...
private IList<IEntity> list;
private IList<Delegate> actions;

public void AddAction<T>(Action<T> handle) where T : IEntity {
    actions.Add(handle);
}
...
```

Thanks.